# Increment variable by X every second

Tags: c#, timer

Am stuck at this section in code.
I want a int variable to increase by X every second till (variable<=required number).
Please guide me.

Edit //
I am having a variable 'i'.
And I want its max value to be say.. 280
I want to perform increment function on variable so that every second value of 'i' increases by 1 till (i=280)

Comment: use `Timer`, add the code in the `Tick` event.

Comment: Use a [timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx) or [`Thread.Sleep`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.sleep.aspx).

Comment: you need to put more about this... any can to understand you. Post the code or what you want

Comment: This is am extremely simple problem with an extremely simple solution. Do your research before asking a question. There are plenty of similar questions here that can help you.

Comment: I did search but wasnt able to find suitable solution...and its still showing error

Comment: so do some research before downarking n question'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you want to make it single-threaded?

```
int i = 0;
while (i < max)
{
    i++;
    Thread.Sleep(x); // in milliseconds
}
```

or multi-threaded:

```
static int i = 0; // class scope

var timer = new Timer { Interval = x }; // in milliseconds
timer.Elapsed += (s,e) =>
    {
        if (++i > max)
            timer.Stop();
    };
timer.Start();
```

Comment: I tried using Thread.Sleep(x);
but its showing "'Thread' doesnt exsist in context

Comment: I didnt get what u said?

Comment: @user1371640: Use `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(x)` or `using System.Threading;` in the top. Or [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=Thread+doesnt+exsist+in+context) :)

Comment: I want to make a linear transformation of an image....and there i want to keep it as animation. I am using VS2012 for windows 8

Comment: I tried 'using System.Threading;' but its still showing same error

Comment: @user1371640: is it a compiler error? Post the full text.

Comment: The name 'Thread' does not exsist in the current context

Comment: @user1371640: [Works for me though](http://ideone.com/dd8uO8).

Answer (score 1):

You can create an instance of Timer class with 1 second interval (passing 1000 in the contructor) and then register the Elapsed event.  Do the increment you are trying in the event handler code.

Answer (score 0):

Without any context this code should do its job:

```
for(int i=0; i<280; i++){
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

But for UI stuff you should use e.g. a Timer.