# Making my integer go up by 1 every second

Tags: c#

I'm extremely new to c# and I'm wondering how I can make a basic timer that counts up by one using an integer. So far I only have

```
int timer = 0;
int max = 10000;

        while ( timer < max )
        {
          timer += 1;

        }
```

I'm assuming this will automatically boost the timer straight to 1000 because there's no speed set. I'm wondering how I can set a speed to this. Thank you.

Comment: This isn't timer, since it doesn't deal with time. Just counter. Use dedicated class Timer from System.Timers.

Comment: Check this link SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15183244/increment-variable-by-x-every-second

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Increment variable by X every second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15183244/increment-variable-by-x-every-second)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);  But the whole system is stopping. another solution is timer. Timer = new Timer();

```
int timer = 0;
int max = 10000;

        while ( timer < max )
        {
          timer += 1;
          System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
```

Comment: This worked however it stopped my code aswell. Can I have an example for the other solution in my code?

Answer (score 3):

There are number of options:

- `while` + [`Thread.Sleep`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.sleep(v=vs.110).aspx) in synchronous code
- `while` + [`Task.Delay`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.delay(v=vs.110).aspx) in asynchronous code
- [`System.Threading.Timer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) in synchronous code

First one is the inefficient one from resources point, because it blocks calling thread.

Second one actually uses third one inside, and is intended for [TAP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap) code.

There also are:

- [`System.Timers.Timer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx), but you should avoid it since it's a [`IComponent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icomponent(v=vs.110).aspx) API wrapper over `System.Threading.Timer` and just adds some `IComponent`-specific trash in your code;
- UI frameworks timers like [`DispatcherTimer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer(v=vs.110).aspx), but they are not general purpose timers and must be used with particular UI framework.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using C# Timer

```
int _counter = 0;
Timer timer;

timer = new Timer();
timer.Interval = 1000;
timer.Elapsed += new EventHandler(TimerEventProcessor);
timer.Start();

private void TimerEventProcessor(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
  _counter += 1;
  if(counter == 1000)  
      timer.Stop();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Thread.Sleep(waitTime)` within the while loop. For example, if you set the wait time to 30 seconds, your counter will increment every 30 seconds.

```
while ( timer < max )
        {
          // Wait for 30 seconds (since the argument is in milliseconds)
          Thread.Sleep(30 * 1000);
          timer += 1;    
        }
```

Comment: so my code should be 
timer += 1;
Thread.Sleep(1); ?

Comment: included the code snippet

Comment: This came up as thread does not exist

Comment: You had to add a `using  System.Threading` statement in the beginning of your code

Comment: Code is working now thanks, But is there any way to run it without everything else pausing? My goal is for my program to check how many seconds has gone by on the timer when someone enters a number, and if the number that was entered exceeds the number on the timer, it will say "number invalid" Thanks in advance
Example of my code is here
http://www.writeurl.com/text/1vs5osewnqx0tlu4pm8o/zf58vadulwwdq2qbvgi8/sdkskd3d1di2cspmqvc3