# I need run add 1 to my var every 1 second in csharp without stopping the program

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to add 1 to a variable meters when ever 1 seconds passed. Task.Delay wont work for some reason.
Here is all my code. Unfortunely im only a beginner at csharp so if you want make you can give me feedback on how to make it better.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int movementSpeed = 6;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    //the variable i want to add 1 to:
    public int meters;
    public double speeding = 5;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        Ymovement();

        void Ymovement()
        {
            var movement = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
            transform.position += new Vector3(0, movement, 0) * Time.deltaTime * movementSpeed;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In general you could use a Timer instance set to tick every second and when it "ticks" you could increment your variable. Something like this answer covers https://stackoverflow.com/a/15183257/513096

Comment: @ArpitKhandelwal in Unity context this always has some drawbacks since Unity API can only be used by the Unity main thread -> with async callbacks you always have to dispatch them back into that main thread

Comment: Did you find an answer to this question? If mine was helpful, please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/405359) to give me some reputation points and help others browsing the search panel that there is a helpful answer here.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty typical use case for `InvokeRepeating`:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int movementSpeed = 6;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    //the variable i want to add 1 to:
    public int meters;
    public double speeding = 5;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        InvokeRepeating("IncreaseMeters", 1f, 1f);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        Ymovement();
    }

    void Ymovement()
    {
        var movement = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        transform.position += new Vector3(0, movement, 0) * Time.deltaTime * movementSpeed;
    }

    void IncreaseMeters()
    {
        meters += 1;
    }
}
```